# Reducing 'min-height' in jquery-steps plugin

Tags: jquery

Steps' plugin for multiple forms in my HTML. You can check how this plugin works from the following URL.

http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples

What I need here is, as per the plugin for all the forms common 'min-height' is getting applied. But I want to control the 'min-height' of the form as per the number of fields in each individual form of different steps. Can anybody help me out on this.

Comment: We get a js file with plugin called 'jquery.steps.js'. What I understood is the 'min-height' is getting controlled by this JS file only. But I don't have that much in depth knowledge of Javascript.

Comment: Can anybody help me out on this......

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the above issue the below is the solution.

Remove the height property for the below class in jquery.steps.css

```
.wizard > .content > .body{height:95%;}
```

In the - jquery.steps.js search for

```
stepTitles.eq(state.currentIndex)
  .addClass("current").next(".body").addClass("current");
```

Should be around line 844. Directly after, add:

```
stepTitles.eq(state.currentIndex).next(".body")
    .each(function () {
    var bodyHeight = $(this).height();
    var padding = $(this).innerHeight() - bodyHeight;
    bodyHeight += padding;
    $(this).after('<div class="' + options.clearFixCssClass + '"></div>');
    $(this).parent().animate({ height: bodyHeight }, "slow");
});
```

The issue will be surely resolved.

Comment: I had the same issue. Above works but I had to remove:  .wizard > .content { min-height: 35em; }
and it worked.

Comment: I also had to remove .wizard > .content > .body{position:absolute} css

Comment: How about when validation error? I get my last field not shown cause the height not automatically adjust when error messages shown.

Comment: It will works properly but it  impact on transition effect.