# JQUERY Wizard Step Plugin: How to dynamically adjust the height of the content for each Step?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-steps

I've already implemented the solution from [How to set a dynamic height on content for each step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819061/how-to-set-a-dynamic-height-on-content-for-each-step/23898163#23898163) and it works great. However, this doesn't work when you are dynamically adding an element inside the step. For example, adding a row in a table dynamically via button, the height doesn't adjust automatically. I'm thinking to adjust the height dynamically when the button is click. Any suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: What is the html code to work with? Do you have a fiddle? You could have the button click trigger an event/function in this function you can call the resize function. Or click on the button triggers resize directly.

Comment: yes but my problem is i dont know whats the resize function for the wizard step? i already tried the .height() but doesn't work. Sample code snippet.

$("#btnAdd").click(function () {
    $(".wizard .content .body").height(500);
});

Comment: If you use [this example](http://jquery-steps.com/Examples#advanced-form) it has no classes `wizzard` `content` or `body` but instead use elements `    headerTag: "h3",    bodyTag: "fieldset". If you use different code, please provide the html code.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [this example](http://jquery-steps.com/Examples#advanced-form) it has no classes `wizard` `content` or `body` but instead use elements `headerTag: "h3",    bodyTag: "fieldset",` so your example would then be

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function () { 
  $("#example-advanced-form h3>fieldset").height(500); 
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work. using .height() will just take effect after you go to the next step and then youll back to the previous step.

Comment: @JoeRaynes please edit [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t83L4xpd/) and click save, then put the link here so we can work from there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I've edited the fiddle already. Basically, im adding a dynamic element on the content. I want to adjust the height automatically.

Comment: @JoeRaynes you need to click save and paste the url here, so we can work from there.

Answer (score 0):

In `jquery.steps.css` file,
just remove `position: absolute`.

```
.wizard > .content > .body
{
    float: left;
    /*position: absolute;*/ <== remove or comment this line
    width: 95%;
    height: 95%;
    padding: 2.5%;
}
```